# Eclipse: Disable property tab contributed from navigator plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I need to hide propery tab called "Resources" contributed by plugin **org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources**

This tab looks like this:

[image]

The description of this tab from plugin:

```
<extension
          point="org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertyContributor">
       <propertyContributor
             contributorId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer"
             labelProvider="org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.workbench.TabbedPropertySheetTitleProvider">
          <propertyCategory category="general"/>
          <propertyCategory category="core"/>
          <propertyCategory category="appearance"/>
          <propertyCategory category="resource"/>
          <propertyCategory category="advanced"/>
       </propertyContributor>
    </extension>
    <extension
          point="org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertyTabs">
       <propertyTabs contributorId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer">
          <propertyTab
                label="%Resource"
                category="resource"
                id="CommonNavigator.tab.Resource"/>
       </propertyTabs>
    </extension>
```

I want to hide this tab, so there will be visible only tab contributed by my plugin.

**Update.**

I have tried activities like this, but is doesnt helps:

```
 <activityPatternBinding
        activityId="com.company.activities.hide"
        isEqualityPattern="true"
        pattern="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources/CommonNavigator.tab.Resource">
     </activityPatternBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

On possibility is to [remove unwanted contribution](http://random-eclipse-tips.blogspot.com/2009/02/eclipse-rcp-removing-unwanted_02.html):

```
final ActionSetRegistry reg = WorkbenchPlugin.getDefault().getActionSetRegistry();
                        final IActionSetDescriptor[] actionSets = reg.getActionSets();
                        final String[] removeActionSets =
                            new String[] { "org.eclipse.search.searchActionSet", "org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.actionSet",
                                    "org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.keyBindings", "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.navigation",
                                    "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.annotationNavigation",
                                    "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.convertLineDelimitersTo",
                                    "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.openExternalFile",
                                    "org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolsSet", "org.eclipse.ui.WorkingSetActionSet",
                                    "org.eclipse.update.ui.softwareUpdates", "org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.openFiles",
                                    "org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.navigation", };

                        for (IActionSetDescriptor actionSet : actionSets) {
                            boolean found = false;
                            for (String removeActionSet : removeActionSets) {
                                if (removeActionSet.equals(actionSet.getId())) {
                                    found = true;
                                }
                            }
                            if (!found) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            final IExtension ext = actionSet.getConfigurationElement().getDeclaringExtension();
                            reg.removeExtension(ext, new Object[] { actionSet });
                        }
```

Comment: Isn't the ID of the propertyTab element something you are looking for? ('CommonNavigator.tab.Resource')?

Comment: Otherwise, I think, you can find it from here: https://eclipse.googlesource.com/platform/eclipse.platform.ui/+/M20131023-0800/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources/plugin.xml

Comment: see Update in question

Comment: How did you applied this binding? It should be applied to an action. Does it work if you remove it programmatically?

Comment: Thats correct. Activity must by applied to an action to remove it. In this case I can hide "Open File.." action for example. But for property tab there is no action, so maybe I cant use activities extansion for disabling this kind of contribution?

Comment: Programmatically there are no Navigator-related actions sets in the registry.